# Overflow:auto with floats AND overflow:visible

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to make two floated divs with `box-shadow` to display the shadows outside of their container. It won't display because their parent has `overflow: auto` set, which cuts off the shadow, but is nevertheless necessary so the parent won't collapse because both child `div`s are floated. If I set the parent to `overflow: visible` it collapses, obviously, because the children are floated. Thanks for any help.
JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zJGVz/

HTML

```
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='child1'></div>
  <div id='child2'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
  overflow: auto;
}
#child1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background: pink;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000;
}
#child2 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: blue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000000;
}
```

Comment: CAn u simulate the same on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you also provide a screenshot of how you want it to display?

Comment: I tweaked the question to match the jsfiddle. @NathanLee, When `overflow:auto` is set, the shadows are not seen outside the parent. When `overflow:visible` is set. The shadows are visible but the parent is collapsed. in the JS fiddle, simply change the overflow value between auto and visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a 5px `margin` to both children on the sides that touch the edge of the parent.

```
#child1 {
  width: 700px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #000000;
  margin:0 0 5px 5px;
}
#child2 {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #000000;
  margin:0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

[See the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zNFSB/3/).

Comment: So far, this looks like the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the overflow to 'visible'

```
overflow: visible;
```